# Highlighting in Foxit Reader

Tags: highlighting, foxit-reader

When highlighting text in Foxit Reader, it introduces spaces in between the letters and highlights letter-wise since the last update.

Screenshot attached for you, on other pages of the document the Highlight Function worked perfectly, I experienced the same problem in other documents I worked with over the last couple of days.

[image]

I use Windows 8.1 and Foxit Reader 7.0.3.916